# jquery event handlers stacking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/PTcw8/4/

```
<div id="container">
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:alert('inline'); return false;"> show me </a>
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="click to change the links onclick event" onclick="javascript:changeOnClick(); return false;" />
</div>​

function changeOnClick() {
    $("#container a").unbind('click');
    $("#container a").on('click', function() {
        alert("changed on the fly");
    })
}​
```

the link has an inline onclick event, i cant unbind it and bind a new handler, they just stack for some reason.

isn't it possible to unbind inline handlers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) an event handler if you have previously attached it with `.bind()`:

> Event handlers attached with .bind() can be removed with .unbind().

For *inline* event handlers, either use:

```
$("#container a").removeAttr("onclick");
```

or

```
$("#container a")[0].onclick = null;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/STvJY/)**.

Comment: ok so im understanding this as the selector is returning an array, but why the handler get stacked? i wonder, it should be replaced, cant accept in a few mins i will once i can

Comment: @Farzad Bekran: jQuery doesn't use `onclick` but `addEventListener`. There is not a value to be overwritten that way.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
       $("#container a").removeAttr("onclick");
       $("#container a").on('click', function() {
          alert("changed on the fly");
       })
    }
);
```